# Stream live audio via gcp in react-native

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-platform, audio-streaming

I want to develop a react-native application which has live audio streamed from one phone to multiple phones. Also this solutions should be hosted on GCP concerning scalability.

I think webRTC is one of the option but not sure how it integrates with GCP.

Comment: What is your latency requirement?  For one-to-multiple, it can be far cheaper to use an alternative mechanism for streaming.  WebRTC gets expensive.

Comment: What is the alternative mechanism ? Also why webRTC get expensive ?